# Is there a difference between "raise exception()" and "raise exception" without parenthesis?

Tags: python, exception

Defining a parameterless exception:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

When raised, is there any difference between:

```
raise MyException
```

and

```
raise MyException()
```

I couldn't find any; is it simply an overloaded syntax?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052991/proper-way-to-raise-exception-in-python#answer-13053014

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not syntactic. Python cannot know whether it will get a class or an instance until runtime.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The short answer is that both `raise MyException` and `raise MyException()` do the same thing.  This first form auto instantiates your exception.

The [relevant section from the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) says:

> *raise* evaluates the first expression as the exception object. It must be either a subclass or an instance of BaseException. If it is a class, the exception instance will be obtained when needed by instantiating the class with no arguments.

That said, even though the semantics are the same,  the first form is microscopically faster, and the second form is more flexible (because you can pass it arguments if needed).

The usual style that most people use in Python (i.e. in the standard library, in popular applications, and in many books) is to use `raise MyException` when there are no arguments.  People only instantiate the exception directly when there some arguments need to be passed.  For example:  `raise KeyError(badkey)`.

Comment: Why would the first form (without parentheses) be microscopically faster?

Comment: @jamesdlin Because the C code to auto-instantiate don't have the interpreted overhead than comes from you making the call yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Go look at [the docs for the `raise` statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement). It's creating an instance of `MyException`.

Comment: It's worth noting that [the syntax for `raise`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) has changed a bit in Python 3. The part that's relevant to this question is the same though (`raise ExceptionType` still creates an instance of the type by calling its constructor with no arguments).

Answer (score -1):

Yep, there is a difference between `ValueError` and `ValueError()`

`ValueError` is a class whereas `ValueError()` creates an instance of a class. This is the reason the `type(ValueError) is type` and `type(ValueError()) is ValueError`

The sole purpose of `raise` is to raise the exception,

> when we use `ValueError`, class will be called which in turn runs the constructor  `ValueError()`
>
> when we use `ValueError()`, the method `ValueError()` is directly called.

Note: `raise ValueError  # shorthand for 'raise ValueError()'`