# Can't catch DoesNotExist exception with Django 1.8 and Python 3.4

Tags: python, django, exception, python-3.x

I have the following view in a Django app:

```
class VideoCreateView(View):
    """
    Handle creating a video
    """
    template_name = 'albums/video_create.html'
    success_template_name = 'albums/video_created.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Display the confirmation dialogue
        """
        # First, get the album
        pk = kwargs['pk']
        try:
            album = Album.objects.get(id=pk)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

        # Render the template
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Generate the video
        """
        # First, get the album
        pk = kwargs['pk']
        try:
            album = Album.objects.get(id=pk)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

        # Trigger build
        if len(album.photo_set.all()) > 0:
            celery_generate_video.delay(album)

            # Send response
            return render(request, self.success_template_name)
        else:
            raise HttpResponseBadRequest
```

This requires an ID for a photo album in the URL, and if the album does not exist, it should raise a 404 error. I've written the following test to check this behaviour:

```
@mock.patch('storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage', FileSystemStorage)
def test_get_does_not_exist(self):
    """
    Test GET requests
    """
    pk = uuid.uuid4()
    url = reverse('video_create', kwargs={
        'pk': pk.urn[9:]
    })
    request = self.factory.get(url)
    request.user = self.user
    response = VideoCreateView.as_view()(request, pk=pk)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

Unfortunately, it's raising the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_does_not_exist (albums.tests.VideoCreateViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/albums/views.py", line 200, in get
    album = Album.objects.get(id=pk)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
albums.models.DoesNotExist: Album matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1125, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/albums/tests.py", line 573, in test_get_does_not_exist
    response = VideoCreateView.as_view()(request, pk=pk)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/digitallife/albums/views.py", line 202, in get
    raise Http404
django.http.response.Http404
```

It looks to me like the exception isn't being caught. I have used this method for catching invalid objects in Django before, but that was in Python 2.7, so I wondered if it was something in Python 3 (this is my first Python 3 Django project). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be [`raise Http404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#id5) ? And  raise HttpResponseBadRequest()?

Comment: @danihp Yes, it should. My bad - I think I need some more caffeine this morning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong in the view. The test result shows it is doing exactly what you want: catching a DoesNotExist, and raising Http404 in response.

The issue is in your test. You're calling the view directly, which means you skip all the middleware that usually does things like handle exceptions and translate them into 404/500 responses. Instead of creating a request via the factory, you should use the built-in test client to call the view:

```
url = ...
response = self.client.get(url)
```

Comment: That's nailed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Its wrong to `raise Http404` with out instantiate a new object. Right way is `raise Http404()` also `raise HttpResponseBadRequest()`.

Comment: @danihp that simply isn't true. It's perfectly valid to raise a class. See (Python core developer) Raymond Hettinger's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16709222/104349), which links to the [reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) which state the same thing.