# Exception vs Exception()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print(Exception is Exception())
print(Exception == Exception())
print(type(Exception))
print(type(Exception())

try:
    raise Exception
except Exception:
    print("Caught Exception with Exception")
try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception:
    print("Caught Exception() with Exception")
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception():
    print("Caught Exception with Exception()")
try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception():
    print("Caught Exception() with Exception()")
```

```
>>> False
>>> False
>>> type
>>> Exception

>>> Caught Exception with Exception
>>> Caught Exception() with Exception
>>> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
>>> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

When would one be used over the other? Does the called form `()` have use-cases where uncalled doesn't suffice? Question's applicable to any exception, not just `Exception`.

Comment: You definitely don't need to call constructor. Use class name.

Comment: I don't get it. One is the class, the other is the instance. Its like with all classes / instances theirof. What exactly is the problem/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `Exception` is a type and `Exception()` is an instance of that class.

Therefore, when you raise an exception you raise an instance of that class:

```
raise Exception("Something happened")
```

When you catch an exception, you're basically saying "this piece of code will deal with any instance of the type `Exception`":

```
try: 
    raise Exception("Something happened")
except Exception as e: 
    print ("Caught an exception:", e)
```

That's also the reason you're seeing the error in your question:

```
>>> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

You're not allowed to catch a type which isn't an `Exception`, and `Exception()` is an instance of `Exception` - and not a derived type.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709222/10133797).

Comment: Unsure why your answer was downvoted; it plus the linked answer are good enough. I did intend to ask on the case when input arguments are irrelevant, as that use case is obvious - I guess it's largely a low-level detail after all.